# Android Studio: Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am programming a small app with a multi language feature.

But when I'm going to check the default language, it wont work. Does anyone know why?

Code:

```
String Lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    if(Lang == "de") {
        Log.i("de", "de");
    }
    else if(Lang == "fr") {
        Log.i("fr", "fr");
    }
    else {
        Log.i("en", "en");
    }
```

Comment: what you expect to see ? what you get ?

Comment: When I'm using the Log.i to show the String ,,Lang", it shows de.
But when it runs, it shows en

Comment: how exactly it doesn;t work? What is the expected and actual result?

Comment: ok, you can't compare strings in Java using `==`. Use `.equals`

Comment: expected result: de;

Comment: Ok, that works!!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
if(lang.equals("de")) {
    Log.i("de", "de");
} else if(lang.equals("fr")) {
    Log.i("fr", "fr");
} else {
    Log.i("en", "en");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(Locale.getDefault()==Locale.GERMANY) {
    Log.i("de", "de");
}
else if(Locale.getDefault()==Locale.FRENCH) {
    Log.i("fr", "fr");
}
else {
    Log.i("en", "en");
}
```

Comment: Try this it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

first you're must compare string using `equals` method , but in your case I will use different approach

```
Locale local = Locale.getDefault();
if (locale.getLanguage().equals(new Locale("de").getLanguage())){ 
   Log.i("de", "de");
}
else if (locale.getLanguage().equals(new Locale("fr").getLanguage())){ 
   Log.i("fr", "fr");
}
else { 
   Log.i("en", "en");
}
```

checkout [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage())